# Angular ng-options no value in edit mode

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a dropdown list created with ng-options. I see that the value is saved, but when I open the form the second time to edit my values the select field has no value.

Here is my code:

Array:

```
$scope.units = [
        {id: "g", name: "g"},
        {id: "mg", name: "mg"}
    ];
```

HTML

```
    Unit id: {{instance.strengthUnit.id}}
    strength: {{instance.strength}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-xs-4">
            <label for="strength" translate="emergencyData.medication.formFields.strength"></label>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="instance.strength" type="text" id="strength"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xs-8">
            <label for="strengthUnit" translate="emergencyData.medication.formFields.unit"></label>
            <select class="form-control" em-select ng-model="instance.strengthUnit.id" id="strengthUnit"
                    ng-options="u.id as u.name for u in units">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The debug row "Unit id: {{instance.strengthUnit.id}}" is showing the value "g" when the form is opened so I know that there is a saved value. The input field strength gets a value in the field. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you make a plunkr or fiddle for this?

Comment: It seems to be the directive I use to change the layout that is the problem. I will continue to find a solution.